# Do I need to transfer my purchased domain?

Tags: web-hosting, google-app-engine, google-cloud

I purchased a .blog domain from "get.blog" and I want to use this domain, but I'm not sure how to do so. When I go to "setup my domain" on their website, they offer options to set it up with either WordPress or Pressable (I don't want to use either). There's also another option, "manual configuration" which asks me to enter up to 4 "Name Servers".

[image]

I have a trial subscription to Google Cloud Services and I would like to try this out for hosting my blog site. Is that possible? If I were to upload my project using Google App Engine, would I be provided a set of "DNS Name Server" addresses that I could configure in the "get.blog" config?

Also, if I decide that I do not want to use Google Cloud Services, is it possible to just host it on one of my machines at home, if I were not expecting much traffic to justify paying for a hosted service?

Comment: It appears to me that all you have to do is chose and set-up your host, set-up your DNS records with your host, use the form above to add your hosts DNS name servers (NS), and wait for it all to propagate throughout the Internet (24 hours is typical).

Comment: If you find this answer helpful to you, please [accept this answer as
correct](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under **Manual Configuration**, you can specify **Google Cloud Platform** nameservers and click on **Set name servers**. Checkout this Google KB to determine your Google Cloud Platform nameservers...,https://cloud.google.com/dns/update-name-servers

Nowadays, web hosting services are available on much cheaper rates, approximately 3 USD per month. IMHO, it isn't a good idea to host a application on home computer, though this thread would help you get started..., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066148/can-i-host-a-web-site-on-my-home-computer

Comment: @Fernando Remember, with web hosting you get what you pay for.  $3 per month is likely going to be on an overcrowded server with way too many other accounts.  It is the only way it is profitable.